# Loading .csv File into SQL Server using SSIS Technique

Tags: ssis

I am new to SQL Server and SSIS. I want to shedule the loading of  .csv file into SQL Server.I want to run the loading for a specific time daily.Please help.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What are you asking? how to schedule SSIS packages? our a full tutorial on how to import files using SSIS? For the latter i suggest to search tutorials in Youtube or a training class, there are many online resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by first creat the table(s) in SQL with the appropriate data types. Then by importing into SQL first and then write your script to update the table but a .bat file would require in order to run your scripts. The following is an example command for a .bat file: sqlcmd -S ServerName -U UserName P Password -i "C:\folder\update.sql"-o "C:\folder\output.txt"

You will need to write the .csv file to a text file and change the extension to .sql

You can use the "Bulk Insert Command" 
Example:
`BULK INSERT FILENAME
DATABASENAME.DBO.TABLENAME
  FROM 'C:\sqlscript\fileName.csv'
  WITH
(
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO`

Hope this helps